# Firefox: How to test prefers-color-scheme?

Tags: css, media-queries, themes

In Firefox 67, one can use media queries to detect user [preference on light or dark theme.](https://davidwalsh.name/demo/prefers-color-scheme.php)

In my version of Firefox (under Ubuntu), it seems that my preference is light theme. That is, the following CSS gives a blue background:

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
   :root {}
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

How can I change my Firefox preferences so that `prefers-color-scheme: dark` 
evaluates to true?

I found an add-on that seems to do the trick, but I must be doing something wrong with my own CSS, as it does not work on my page.
[Dark Website forcer](https://davidwalsh.name/demo/prefers-color-scheme.php)

Comment: This isn't of much help to you, but on macOS, I can only get it to change if I change it in *Preferences* > *General*. :|

Comment: What is the :root property for?

Comment: @rubo77 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root

Comment: Sure, but why did you add the empty selektor here?

Comment: @rubo77 ah, my mistake, i was thinking to put some variables in there, depending on user preference, but this was not needed for minimal working example.

Answer (score 76):

From Firefox 87, a feature to test `prefers-color-scheme` in the devtools is enabled by default, without any need to set a configuration flag. You can find it in the inspector tab:

[image: The Firefox Developer tools, with prefers color scheme toggles circled]

- Choosing the sun button simulates light mode;
- Choosing the moon button simulates dark mode;
- With no button selected, your operating system default will be used, as per normal.

---

In some older versions of Firefox, this feature existed behind a flag. To test on one of those versions, you can thus enable this by going to `about:config`, and setting the `devtools.inspector.color-scheme-simulation.enabled` property to `true`. Once that's done, you'll find the controls for it in the same place as in the modern devtools, but as a single paintbrush icon rather than today's sun/moon toggle buttons.

Answer (score 52):

You can update the style used by Firefox by going to `about:config` and adding a new property `ui.systemUsesDarkTheme` of integer type with value `1`.

It doesn't automatically update the value on active pages in the same way that it does when you're updating OS settings in Windows or Mac, but if you refresh the page after updating it will pick up.

You can confirm the browser setting is correct by viewing the [example on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme#Result)

Edit:
On firefox 71 the update is applied to active pages without refresh

Comment: FYI: to add a new property, you have to right-click anywhere on about:config :)

Comment: Note, that the new value has to be integer as noted above, boolean true wont work!

Comment: In my case (on Fedora/Linux with GNOME) this does not work anymore in Firefox 83, as it seems – even after a restart.

Comment: In my case, this changes the style of Firefox (menu bar) but not the style of the page...

Answer (score 4):

Just for the sake of completeness: If everything fails, there is a [Firefox add-on called “**Dark Website Forcer**”](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/dark-mode-website-switcher/?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=q2a&utm_content=https://stackoverflow.com/q/56401662/5008962&campaign=stackoverflow) ([also on GitHub](https://github.com/rugk/website-dark-mode-switcher/)).
It changes the style by reading the CSS of the website and re-applying the parts for the dark version again, if you want to have a dark one. As such, it also can only force a dark website, *not* the light one. The Readme [has a detailed explanation why](https://github.com/rugk/website-dark-mode-switcher#important-limitations).

**Disclosure:**  I'm the author of this add-on.