# Disable Safari's Dark mode, independently from OS setting

Tags: macos, safari, macos-big-sur

I wonder if it is possible to deactivate the dark mode / force activate the bright mode on MacOS Safari independently. Even if the system is currently set to auto or dark mode.

-> From Safari's system settings; not from a website's code.

I prefer using the system's dark mode but I sometimes need to debug my apps in Safari with the normal color scheme.

Comment: Theoretically a website should check it with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme - In chrome I know a way to change this on the fly per website, not sure how to cope with this in safari

Comment: For example for chrome https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57606960/how-can-i-emulate-prefers-color-scheme-media-query-in-chrome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Too easy. The Elements-tab in Safari's Dev tools provides a funny button for toggling the color scheme:

[image]

Thanks @JulianKleine for pointing me in the right direction!