# How to configure @nuxt/tailwind + typography with dark mode

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-content

I'm building a blog using [nuxt.js/content](https://content.nuxtjs.org/), I want to apply dark mode using the plugin [color mode](https://color-mode.nuxtjs.org/).

how can I apply the dark mode to the articles?

I tried to do `dark: prose-dark`, didn't work.

```html
<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ $content, params }) {
    const post = await $content('posts', params.slug).fetch()
    return { post }
  }
}
</script>


<template>
  <div class="wrapper p-5 mt-20">
    <div class="max-w-screen-lg mx-auto px-3 py-5">
      <h1 class="text-6xl text-gray-800 font-medium"> {{ post.title }}</h1>
      <div class="img max-w-full mx-auto m-5">
        <img :src="require(`~/assets/${post.cover}`)" :alt="post.title" class="rounded-xl shadow-lg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <nuxt-content class="prose prose-lg max-w-screen-lg mx-auto px-3 my-5" :document="post" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: What is prose dark: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-typography#color-modifiers ?

Comment: @kissu a customized shared styles I added to the `tailwind.config.js`, that I found here: https://github.com/nuxt/content/blob/939caf36c547a6b4af6e303c52ed5989a5dea2f0/packages/theme-docs/src/tailwind.config.js#L92

Comment: Did you told your browser to use dark mode? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59223868/8816585

Comment: @kissu yes, I have a component to switch the theme

Comment: Do you have a [repro]?

Comment: No I'm just asking if anyone tried to do the dark mode, using content and color mode..

Comment: I'm asking for it because it is probably working well (and `nuxt/content` is not relevant here IMO). Probably an issue in your tailwind config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the boilerplate: https://github.com/kissu/nuxt-tailwind-typography-darkmode-boilerplate

It comes with:

- [Nuxt](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js) v2 since v3 is not public yet
- [@nuxt/content](https://github.com/nuxt/content) even it's totally unrelated to the actual issue
- [@nuxtjs/tailwindcss](https://github.com/nuxt-community/tailwindcss-module), v2.1 + JIT enabled
- [@nuxtjs/color-mode](https://github.com/nuxt-community/color-mode-module) for dark mode support
- [@tailwindcss/typography](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tailwindcss/typography) configured to support `dark: prose-light`
- basic working ESlint + Prettier configuration

This is basically an updated version of [the tailwind configuration](https://github.com/nuxt/content/blob/939caf36c547a6b4af6e303c52ed5989a5dea2f0/packages/theme-docs/src/tailwind.config.js) for the [@nuxt/content-theme-docs](https://content.nuxtjs.org/installation) without being stuck to write documentation files only. (there is maybe a way of doing this out of the box but I did not found it)

This configuration was heavily inspired by this awesome post from Adam: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-typography/issues/69#issuecomment-752946920

I'm not sure what [tailwindcss-dark-mode](https://github.com/ChanceArthur/tailwindcss-dark-mode) is really used for since it is not really active and that the few variants that I've tried are already working out of the box with Tailwind 2. But I found this interesting issue in case it may be helpful one day: https://github.com/ChanceArthur/tailwindcss-dark-mode/issues/37#issue-681948280

The current configuration (`tailwind.config.js`) is essentially relying on toggling buttons at the top of the page because of `darkMode: 'class'`. If you set it to `media`, you can either toggle it in your system or go to Chrome's dev tools and `ctrl + shift + p` and choose your any `prefers-color-scheme` for testing purposes.

[image]